# What is the use of dynamic_pointer_cast in C++? When is it used? What are alternatives for dynamic_pointer_cast?

Tags: c++

I was reading about dynamic_pointer_cast. I found that we can dynamically upcast or downcast the shared pointer of one type to another at run time but i did't understand the concept completely. Shall both the classes must have same properties? If the properties must be same then what is need of dynamic casting?

Comment: *Shall both the classes must have same properties?* It's no clear to me what you mean by that.

Comment: What i mean is that if we are type casting shared pointer to one class to shared pointer of another class, Should those two classes must have same variables defined in them?

Comment: @RSahu can you explain me the concept of dynamic pointer casting? like when is it used and how?

Comment: A dynamic pointer cast essentially applies a `dynamic_cast` on the raw pointer held within. If you don't know what a `dynamic_cast` is or what it's good for, you need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: *"When is it used?"* - Hardly ever. *"What are the alternatives?"* - None. If you need it, you need it. That's why it is there. You can probably leave it for now and come back to this should you ever need to transform one type of shared_ptr into another.

Comment: @BoPersson suppose i am creating a shared pointer of base class type using dynamic_pointer_cast from shared pointer of derived class type. Can i call base class member function using casted shared pointer?

Comment: @A.Saroj - Yes, but you can calls base class members on the derived class as well. Dynamic cast is for when you have a pointer to Base, which may or may not actually point to a Derived. Then you can get a pointer to Derived, if it actually is that, or an empty pointer if otherwise. (I have never seen a case where this was actually useful. Most often you call virtual functions on the Base pointer and it works without a cast).

Comment: @BoPersson It is useful in cases where the class API is not completely polymorphic and calling code needs to act differently based on the concrete type of the class. Some would classify this as a design smell.

Answer (score 5):

`dynamic_pointer_cast` is used to convert `std::shared_ptr` type, e.g. from the pointer on a base class to a pointer on a derived class:

```
#include <memory>

struct A{ virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B: A {};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> pA = std::make_shared<B>();
    std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(pA);
}
```

So `dynamic_pointer_cast` is a convenience wrapper around `dynamic_cast`:

```
template< class T, class U > 
std::shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r ) noexcept
{
    if (auto p = dynamic_cast<typename std::shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get())) {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>{r, p};
    } else {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>{};
    }
}
```